# Android: Difference between console and adb connections?

Tags: android, console, adb

From https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#howadbworks:

> Note that each emulator/device instance acquires a pair of sequential
>   ports — an even-numbered port for console connections and an
>   odd-numbered port for adb connections.

I read this statement and wonder what is the difference between console and adb connections?

Comment: Many people do not like answering *what is the difference between `A` and `B`* questions which often read like *I do not know anything - please explain everything*. You will get much better results with questions worded like *I know `A` and I just started learning about `B`. But they seem similar. Please explain how exactly `B` is different from `A`*

Answer (score 1):

In that context `console` stands for the `emulator console`. As the name suggests - it is only applicable to emulator instances.

You can find more information about using the `emulator console` at [developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#console)